# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.polls' in django tutorial while testing

Tags: python, django, testing

I am coding along tutorial from django documentation site: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial05/

I got a following problem:
While trying to run test on my app (with: `py manage.py test polls` in Pycharm commndline)
i get following error:

```
> ImportError: Failed to import test module: mysite.polls Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\micha\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoTutorial\lib\unittest\loader.py",
> line 470, in _find_test_path
>     package = self._get_module_from_name(name)   File "C:\Users\micha\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoTutorial\lib\unittest\loader.py",
> line 377, in _get_module_from_name
>     __import__(name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.polls'
```

The file structre of my project is as follwoing: [link to the directory tree img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSQs8.png)

It looks like testing unit automaticcaly adds 'mysite' in front of 'polls'

What i tried:
I have tried to lookup for an answer in django test documentation.
Only solution that i was able to find was to change command to like like this:

```
py manage.py test polls.tests
```

Then it runs my test properely.

As far as I understand django documentation, django should automatically find every 'test*' file in polls yet in case of mine it cannot find 'polls' module.

Can you tell me why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your polls app in your settings file?

INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, i did as follows: 
`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #'polls',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',`
]

Answer (score 0):

From django documentation : "Test discovery is based on the unittest module’s built-in test discovery. By default, this will discover tests in any file named “test*.py” under the current working directory."

It says current working directory ie. where the manage.py is, your test are located in the polls folder that is why polls.test is required.

You can also provide a path to a directory to discover tests below that directory: ./manage.py test polls/

Comment: So when i work from the /polls directory then  command:
 'py ../manage.py test polls'  does work (so with the double ..) 

But working from /mysite directory, the command: 
'py manage.py test /polls'  gives an old error. 

And /polls is under current working directory (/mysite) so it should work. Shouldn't it?